unstack on single row index
data = {
    'Store': ['Store_A', 'Store_A', 'Store_B', 'Store_B'],
    'Product': ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Apples', 'Bananas'],
    'Sales': [200, 350, 150, 500]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(['Store'], inplace=True)  
df.unstack()

my output is:
         Store  
Product  Store_A     Apples
         Store_A    Bananas
         Store_B     Apples
         Store_B    Bananas
Sales    Store_A        200
         Store_A        350
         Store_B        150
         Store_B        500
dtype: object

Why is the store column, which is a row index, not converted into a column index?
why Product and Sales will become a column index?
My expectation : 

Could you add the output you were expecting?

My expectation is that the row index (store ) will become a column index

Right, you said that, but what would that actually look like?

In this output, the product (column index) and sales ( column index) have been converted into a row index, while the task of the unstack is to convert the row index  into a column index.

Right, but what output were you expecting? Please show what you mean instead of just describing.

Added a photo to the post

I don't get it. In the picture, the store labels don't correspond with their values. They don't seem to correspond with anything, since there should be 4 columns.

Stacking/unstacking a single index results in a vector (i.e. a Series). Pandas doesn't have a way to represent row vectors specifically, so what you get is essentially a column.
I suspect what you actually wanted was to set Product as the remaining index, which you can do with either .set_index().unstack() or .pivot().
df.set_index(['Product', 'Store']).unstack()
# or
df.pivot(columns='Store', index='Product')

          Sales        
Store   Store_A Store_B
Product                
Apples      200     150
Bananas     350     500


P.S. I had to read between the lines to write a sensible answer. If the question gets clarified, I can edit.

IIUC you want the Store values to be the columns, and Product and Sales be the two rows.
Just use a simple set_index and T to transpose with the Store values as columns.
Try:
df.set_index('Store').T

Output:
Store   Store_A  Store_A Store_B  Store_B
Product  Apples  Bananas  Apples  Bananas
Sales       200      350     150      500

As mentioned in the Pandas documentation here, about pd.DataFrane.unstack:

Pivot a level of the (necessarily hierarchical) index labels.
Returns a DataFrame having a new level of column labels whose inner-most level consists of the pivoted index labels.
If the index is not a MultiIndex, the output will be a Series (the analogue of stack when the columns are not a MultiIndex).

Basically the index is pushed into the inner most level, and the rest of the columns are transposed. That's why your code is not achieving the desired result. Also, your index is not a MultiIndex, that's why your output right now is a Series instead of a DataFrame.

If you don't want duplicate columns, use:
df.set_index(['Store', 'Product']).T

Output:
Store   Store_A         Store_B        
Product  Apples Bananas  Apples Bananas
Sales       200     350     150     500


The question's asking "why", it's not asking how to do something else, though that is good to include.

@wjandrea Done.

df.set_index(['Store', 'Product']).T would make more sense to me. That way you don't get columns with mixed types, plus the repeated Store labels get combined.

@wjandrea Nice one, edited.
